# Как получить значение у translate? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть элемент:

```
<square class="square" style="transform: translate(54px, 54px);"></square>
```

У него есть атрибут style, в нем есть стиль transform.
Получаю его таким способом:

```
elem.style.transform
```

После чего получаю такой результат:

```
translate(54px, 54px)
```

Как получить значения в скобках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ это использовать [регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), вот так:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('square.square')
let transform = elem.style.transform
let re = /translate\((.*?)\)/

console.log(transform.match(re)[1])
```

```html
<square class="square" style="transform: translate(54px, 54px);"></square>
```

Я использовал метод [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) на строку, первым аргументом привёл регулярное выражение. Я обращаюсь к первому индексу, а не к нулевому т.к. в 0'ом хранится сама строка полностью, а уже в первом само значение `translate`, т.к. как вы можете заметить, оно обёрнуто в скобки (скобки без символа `\` сзади).

Стоит учитывать, что подобный код не будет работать с `translateX`, `translateY` и `translateZ`. Также стоит учитывать, что если в `transform` не будет `translate`'а, то метод `match` вернёт `null`, и код выдаст ошибку: `TypeError: transform.match(...) is null`.

Comment: Можно ли из этого получить массив из чисел? Без указания единицы измерения

Comment: Да пожалуй, можно. Нужно использовать второе регулярное выражение на уже найденное в скобах значение.

Comment: @dujor21 вообще, если у вас появилась новая задача, нужно [задавать *новый вопрос*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), а также включать вашу попытку решения, даже если она не правильная.

Comment: @dujor21 подскажу, нужно использовать `\d+` (Такое выражение значит число длиной 1 или более символов), а также флаг `g` означающий global.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, написать выражение? Не очень понимаю эту тему, но в любом случае большое спасибо.

Comment: @dujor21 извиняюсь, не заметил вашего комментария. Вот регулярное выражение: `/\d+/g`, не совсем понимаю, чего вам непонятно. Как и где применить, вы должны догадаться сами (информацию о том как это сделать, я вам предоставил), иначе вы не научитесь работать с JavaScript'ом.